# GDBus/PolicyKit error in LXDE

Tags: lxde, d-bus, polkit, parabola

I am using LXDE with Parabola (a libre derivative of Arch Linux). When I log in to the desktop environment, a window pops up with the following error:

`GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject`

What does this error mean and is it anything serious? What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue seems to be the same as [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574456/cant-start-polkit-mate-authentication-agent). The polkit authentication agent cannot register with polkit, which is causing the error window in LXDE.